# How to add geom_col to my code appropriately

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

```r
datapasta::df_paste(head(df,45)[,c('A.','Object','Colour')])
#> Error in unclass(x)[...]: subscript out of bounds


data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                               A. = c(113,34,NA,9,11,28,41,66,12,23.2,
                                      22.8,21.7,22.7,22.2,21.7,22.5,23.4,
                                      NA,23.6,21.3,22.8,17.8,23.1,23.5,
                                      22.3,25.6,23.6,23.7,23.9,22.6,22.9,
                                      23.7,26.2,24.3,21.9,22.5,25.2,22.6,
                                      24.1,26.1,23,24,23.9,26.7,NA),
                           Object = c("Bag","shoe","shoe","belt","shoe",
                                      "belt","belt","Bag","Bag","belt","belt",
                                      "Bag","Bag","shoe","shoe","belt",
                                      "shoe","belt","belt","Bag","Bag","belt",
                                      "Bag","shoe","shoe","belt","shoe",
                                      "belt","belt","Bag","shoe","shoe","belt",
                                      "shoe","belt","belt","Bag","shoe",
                                      "shoe","belt","shoe","belt","belt",
                                      "Bag",NA),
                           Colour = c("red","black","black","red","black",
                                      "blue","blue","red","blue","red","red",
                                      "blue","red","black","black","red",
                                      "black","blue","blue","red","red",
                                      "black","black","red","black","blue",
                                      "blue","red","red","black","black","red",
                                      "black","blue","blue","red","red",
                                      "black","black","red","black","blue",
                                      "blue","red",NA)
               )
#>       A. Object Colour
#> 1  113.0    Bag    red
#> 2   34.0   shoe  black
#> 3     NA   shoe  black
#> 4    9.0   belt    red
#> 5   11.0   shoe  black
#> 6   28.0   belt   blue
#> 7   41.0   belt   blue
#> 8   66.0    Bag    red
#> 9   12.0    Bag   blue
#> 10  23.2   belt    red
#> 11  22.8   belt    red
#> 12  21.7    Bag   blue
#> 13  22.7    Bag    red
#> 14  22.2   shoe  black
#> 15  21.7   shoe  black
#> 16  22.5   belt    red
#> 17  23.4   shoe  black
#> 18    NA   belt   blue
#> 19  23.6   belt   blue
#> 20  21.3    Bag    red
#> 21  22.8    Bag    red
#> 22  17.8   belt  black
#> 23  23.1    Bag  black
#> 24  23.5   shoe    red
#> 25  22.3   shoe  black
#> 26  25.6   belt   blue
#> 27  23.6   shoe   blue
#> 28  23.7   belt    red
#> 29  23.9   belt    red
#> 30  22.6    Bag  black
#> 31  22.9   shoe  black
#> 32  23.7   shoe    red
#> 33  26.2   belt  black
#> 34  24.3   shoe   blue
#> 35  21.9   belt   blue
#> 36  22.5   belt    red
#> 37  25.2    Bag    red
#> 38  22.6   shoe  black
#> 39  24.1   shoe  black
#> 40  26.1   belt    red
#> 41  23.0   shoe  black
#> 42  24.0   belt   blue
#> 43  23.9   belt   blue
#> 44  26.7    Bag    red
#> 45    NA   <NA>   <NA>


df.summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Object,Colour) %>%
  summarise(
    mn = mean(A., na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(A., na.rm = TRUE)
  )
#> Error in df %>% group_by(Object, Colour) %>% summarise(mn = mean(A., na.rm = TRUE), : could not find function "%>%"
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Object'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
ggplot(df.summary, aes(Object, mn)) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = mn-sd, ymax = mn+sd, color = Colour),
    position = position_dodge(0.3), width = 0.2
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Colour), position = position_dodge(0.3)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#00FF00")) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Colour),data = df.summary)+
  geom_col(fill = alpha("#2C77BF", .3))+
geom_col(aes(y = A.),fill = alpha("#2C77BF", .009), position = position_dodge(0.3), data= df)
#> Error in ggplot(df.summary, aes(Object, mn)): could not find function "ggplot"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This image style is what I am targeting to achieve
[image: Target image]

But this is an example of the image I have gotten from my codes
[image: this is image of my code]

I have a target plot I want to achieve, and that is what has been uploaded as Target (1). I have used my codes to create my plot but the bars are fused together with others than individually. Can you help with the codes for the geom_col(). I am thinking that is where I am getting wrongly

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you used the wrong dataset for the bars and the points. As the bars reflect the mean use `df.summary` for `geom_col` and as the points reflect the raw data use `df` for geom_point. Additionally I use `position_jitterdodge` for the points to avoid overplotting and added an `position_dodge` for the lines.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df.summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Object, Colour) %>%
  summarise(
    mn = mean(A., na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(A., na.rm = TRUE)
  ) |> 
  tidyr::drop_na()

ggplot(df.summary, aes(Object, mn)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Colour), position = position_dodge(.6), alpha = .5, width = .6) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = mn - sd, ymax = mn + sd, color = Colour),
    position = position_dodge(0.6), width = 0.2
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(y = A., color = Colour), data = df, position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.6, jitter.width = .1), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Colour, group = Colour), position = position_dodge(.6)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#00FF00"), aesthetics = c("color", "fill"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and correction. the code worked perfectly. Grateful